# Module Not Found. Selenium suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, module, modulenotfounderror

What basically happened is this: The selenium module suddenly stopped working.

I downloaded selenium using the `pip install selenium` method.
it worked well and good. I was using it to try a data scraping project. The thing is...**It worked.**
I got all the values I wanted, and I was working on a way to save that data in a file.
But then, suddenly...it started showing errors that the selenium module wasn't there. Which was weird because I didn't actually change anything.

[Image for reference. I even tried reinstalling it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvZiF.png)

All the file locations are in PATH--I got that covered. The selenium module is definitely present.
I don't know if it's important but the error first began when I was working on another project that created CSV and text files. (I was learning how to use them)

I don't think it's necessary...but here is the code of the main thing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
TCases=[]
DCases=[]
RCases=[]

def LogValue():

  chrome_options = Options()
  chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\elect\OneDrive\Desktop\CDriver\chromedriver.exe' , options=chrome_options)
  driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
  cases = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="maincounter-number"]')
  Plist = []
  for i in range(len(cases)):
      Plist.append(cases[i].text)
  TCases.append(Plist[0])
  DCases.append(Plist[1])
  RCases.append(Plist[2])
  driver.close()
  return Plist
  

print(LogValue())
```

a lot of unused stuff cause I was still working on it.

Comment: I'm not sure why only the first instance of selenium usage is showing error and not in the rest of the places. Usually an IDE/text editor should mark all instances of selenium if it hasn't found the selenium package. Have you tried using other import type like `import selenium.webdriver`?

Comment: Hi, issue could be related to pipenv? 
Check my quick video for python with selenium https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCeBy0128Ac
Video is based on windows, if you are using mac then please follow pipenv steps for mac